# Return a String Representation of a Node Class in Reverse Order using Recursion

Tags: python, string, recursion, reverse

I have a class node:

```
class LinkedNode:
    __slots__ = 'val', 'next'
    def __init__(self, val, next):
        self.val = val  # element at the node
        self.next = next  # next node reference

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.val)

    __repr__ = __str__
```

I am attempting to return a string representation of the list of node in reverse order, but using recursion. It does not modify the node, but only returns a string representation of the node. I also want to format it correctly.

So if the node was:

```
{1, 2, 3}
```

I want to use a recursive function so that it can print:

```
3, 2, 1
```

I have the following function:

```
def reverse_str(node):
    str_rep = ""
    if node is None:
        return str_rep
    else:
        str_rep = str(node.val)
        # For str(node.val), there is a class function that returns 
        # str(self.val)
        str_rep = reverse_str(node.next) + str_rep + ", "
```

If the node was:

```
{1, 2, 3}
```

My outcome is:

```
3, 2, 1, # Trailing comma
```

I cannot seem to figure out a way to rid the trailing comma while keeping the function a recursive one. This is probably a simple if / else statement, but I am not sure what to test to see if this is the first head node. I also do not want to modify the Node class.

Any suggestions or ideas would be helpful! Thanks.

Comment: What is meant by the node was {1, 2, 3}?

Comment: @EPo {1, 2, 3} is an example of what the node might be. A node could also be {3, 5, 6, 8} and so forth. Each of the element in those examples are nodes. (They sort of stack upon each other)

Comment: Is this the list of node.val? I thing you are misusing the wording, node is not anything generic in python snd class you define never shows as  {1, 2, 3} as there is no rept or str method. also in python  {1, 2, 3} is a set, it does not preserve order of elements.

Comment: Also the use of slots class varible is confusing - any special meaning attached to it?

Comment: @EPo Yeah, I think I am misusing the wording - sorry about that. I have a custom function for the class to return the linked nodes (I'll add it above shortly). I also meant to use the bracket as a way to represent the nodes stacked on top of each other; sorry for confusing it with sets.

Answer (score 0):

Likely you need `','.join(a, b)`, but deeper problems with code   lie elsewhere, see comments.

Basically, you are trying to work out a chain, but python is not immidiatey too good to for holding pointers, as opposed to C. Unless you have to use a class, consider your  data structure to be a list of dictionaries for example.

Comment: Hmm,  I don't think ", ".join( str_rep) would work because since this is a recursive function, it would add multiple ", "s.

For example, if the node was 1->2->3->4->None, the reverse_str function would return:
 4, ,,  , ,, ,,  ,  , ,,  , 3, ,,  , 2, 1
as a result.

I think I need a special case for when I get to the end of the list at the beginning in order to format the commas correctly.

Thanks for your help so far though!

Comment: Commas are not the problem, the problem is waking your list to get a list the you concat with with join.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an attribute that acts as a "helper" to generate a list of nodes, and then use the `__str__` method to return a string:

```
class _List:
  def __init__(self, _val=None):
    self.val, self._next = _val, None
  def insert_val(self, _val):
    if self.val is None:
      self.val = _val
    else:
      getattr(self._next, 'insert_val', lambda x:setattr(self, '_next', _List(x)))(_val)
  @property
  def to_list(self):
    return [self.val, *getattr(self._next, 'to_list', [])]
  def __str__(self):
    return ', '.join(list(map(str, self.to_list))[::-1])

l = _List()
for i in range(10):
  l.insert_val(i)

print(l)
```

Output:

```
9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0
```

Comment: `getattr(self._next, 'insert_val', lambda x:setattr(self, '_next', _List(x)))(_val)` thats quite a machinery.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for the case where the node is None (i.e the previous node was the last one) and treat that case differently, for instance:

```
def reverse_str(node):
    if node is None:
        return None
    else:
        str_rep = str(node.val)
        # For str(node.val), there is a class function that returns
        # str(self.val)
        s = reverse_str(node.next)
        str_rep = s + ", " + str_rep if s else str_rep
        return str_rep

three = LinkedNode(3, None)
two = LinkedNode(2, three)
one = LinkedNode(1, two)

print(reverse_str(one))
```

**Output**

```
3, 2, 1
```